# SQL CASE WHEN, when i want an "including" row

Tags: sql, case, obiee

I need some help.

Lets say i have a table

```
ID  Mark  Transmition
1   Ford  A
2   Ford  A
3   Ford  M
4   BMW   M
5   BMW   M
6   Ford  A
```

And now i need to do a case when.

```
CASE WHEN mark = 'Ford' then 'Ford'
     WHEN mark = 'Ford' and Transmition = 'A' then ' including Fords with automatic transmitions'
```

And I have to do this using case when, not case when exists. Since I need to use it in an OBIEE report.

The result i need is something like this:

```
Mark                                  Count
Ford                                  4
inc Ford with automatic transmition   3
```

But the results evaluate to TRUE in bith of the cases...

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: So what's the question ?

Comment: it evaluates to TRUE both time... somehow i need to have rows like this:

    Ford                                        4
     including fords with automatic transmition 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN mark = 'Ford' THEN 'Ford' END AS Mark,
COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 t
WHERE mark = 'Ford'
GROUP BY mark
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN mark = 'Ford' AND Transmition = 'A' 
              THEN 'including Fords with automatic transmitions' END AS Mark,
COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 t
WHERE mark = 'Ford'
AND Transmition = 'A' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN mark = 'Ford' AND Transmition = 'A' 
              THEN 'including Fords with automatic transmitions' END
```

Result:

```
|                                        MARK | COUNT(*) |
|---------------------------------------------|----------|
|                                        Ford |        4 |
| including Fords with automatic transmitions |        3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question, but it seems you try to avoid `null` rows by pointing out `case when` vs `case when exists`.

What about

```
SELECT
  ' including Fords with automatic transmitions' AS "DESCRIPTION",
  COUNT("ID") AS "POCET"
FROM some_table
WHERE "Mark" = 'Ford' AND "Transmition" = 'A'
GROUP BY "Mark"

UNION ALL

SELECT
  "Mark",
  COUNT("ID") AS "POCET"
FROM some_table
WHERE "Mark" = 'Ford'
GROUP BY "Mark"
```

Comment: Updated answer, because question changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `CASE` like this :

```
SELECT Mark, count(1) FROM car GROUP By Mark
UNION
SELECT 'Including '||Mark||' with automatic transmitions' as MM, count(1) FROM car WHERE Transmition = 'A' GROUP By MM;
```

Result:

```
|                                        MARK | COUNT(*) |
|---------------------------------------------|----------|
|                                         BMW |        2 |
|                                        Ford |        4 |
| including Fords with automatic transmitions |        3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
SELECT MARK,Count(1) AS Count FROM
 (
   SELECT CASE WHEN mark = 'Ford' and Transmition = 'A' then ' including Fords with automatic transmitions'
          WHEN mark = 'Ford' and Transmition <> 'A' then 'Ford'
          Else 'BMW'
          END Mark
   FROM Table1
) AS T Group By T.Mark
```

**O/P :**

```
MARK                                            COUNT
including Fords with automatic transmitions     3
BMW                                             2
Ford                                            1
```

## [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd65c/12)